# Difference between TensorFlow model fit and train_on_batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am building a vanilla DQN model to play the OpenAI gym Cartpole game.

However, in the training step where I feed in the state as input and the target Q values as the labels, if I use `model.fit(x=states, y=target_q)`, it works fine and the agent can eventually play the game well, but if I use `model.train_on_batch(x=states, y=target_q)`, the loss won't decrease and the model will not play the game anywhere better than a random policy.

I wonder what is the difference between `fit` and `train_on_batch`? To my understanding, `fit` calls `train_on_batch` with a batch size of 32 under the hood which should make no difference since specifying the batch size to equal the actual data size I feed in makes no difference.

The full code is here if more contextual information is needed to answer this question: https://github.com/ultronify/cartpole-tf

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`model.fit` will train 1 or more epochs. That means it will train multiple batches. `model.train_on_batch`, as the name implies, trains only one batch.

To give a concrete example, imagine you are training a model on 10 images. Let's say your batch size is 2. `model.fit` will train on all 10 images, so it will update the gradients 5 times. (You can specify multiple epochs, so it iterates over your dataset.) `model.train_on_batch` will perform one update of the gradients, as you only give the model on batch. You would give `model.train_on_batch` two images if your batch size is 2.

And if we assume that `model.fit` calls `model.train_on_batch` under the hood (though I don't think it does), then `model.train_on_batch` would be called multiple times, likely in a loop. Here's pseudocode to explain.

```
def fit(x, y, batch_size, epochs=1):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for batch_x, batch_y in batch(x, y, batch_size):
            model.train_on_batch(batch_x, batch_y)
```

Comment: Does that mean when the size of x equals to batch_size, fit, and train_on_batch should be the same? That's kind of the case for me since my x has 32 samples and the default batch size for TensorFlow is 32 as well.

Comment: Don't think of `fit` and `train_on_batch` as the same. `fit` trains multiple batches, and `train_on_batch` trains one batch. But in your case when your entire dataset fits in a single batch, then yes, `fit` will only run over one batch, just like `train_on_batch`. There is still a difference, though, because you could specify multiple epochs to `fit` and you cannot do that with `train_on_batch`. PS if you only have 32 samples, neural networks probably aren't the right tool to use.

Comment: I see. Yea, I was training a DQN and I sample 32 frames for each game play episode.